# PHPRedis key deleted and modified datetime

Tags: php, redis

How to know

1. Deleted datetime of a redis key (means previously a particular key
   exists but deleted recently I need to know when was that particular
   key deleted).
2. Modified datetime of a redis key (I want to know last modified
   datetime of a particular key).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: ok sure. Thanks Quintin Balsdon.

Answer (score 0):

That information is not accounted by Redis out of the box - if you need to track it, you'll need to store the datetime whenever a key is deleted/modified (for example using a Sorted Set to store the key's name and the timestamp as score) yourself after each deletion/modification.

Comment: If a redis key is modified we can update datetime manually using hset() but how can we check modified datetime if the key is no more (deleted).

Comment: When your code deletes the key it should make note of the time. Alternatively, look into keyspace notifications in Redis but note that PubSub doesn't ensure delivery.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, got to know few things regarding "Redis Keyspace Notifications" in https://redis.io/topics/notifications